# Probability with conditions

Tags: probability, combinatorics, problem-solving, conditional-probability

I'm not experienced in maths, so please pardon my mathematical presentation of the issue.

If *n* represents the number of books in a library, and *x* represents the number of pages in each book; what is the probability for the following event to happen:

> *A-E = B-D = 0*

Where:

> *A = 1 + 2 + 3 + ... + n*
>
> *B = x1 + x2 + x3 + ... + xn*
>
> *C = (1+x1) + (2+x2) + (3+x3) + … + (n+xn)*
>
> *D = ∑ (i+xi) " The sum of even numbers calculated in C "*
>
> *E = ∑ (j+xj) " The sum of odd numbers calculated in C "*

Conditions:

*x* (elements of B) are randomly selected from a finite set of positive integers

*x > 2*

*u* represents the number of even numbers calculated in *C*

*w* represents the number of odd numbers calculated in *C*

*u = w = n/2* (if *n = 114* then we should have *57* even numbers and *57* odd numbers in *C*)

*n > 19*

*n* & *u* & *w* are multiples of *19*

Comment: What does the event "$A-E = B-D = 0$" represent in words?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Henry, A-E = B-D = 0 in words " what are the chances to have A=E and B=D", A is the sum of natural numbers from 1 to n, B is the sum of random natural numbers that are greater than 2.